# CTEs not working when theres IF condition in the query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-optimization

I am trying to add functionality on my query to select which query will be executed on a certain condition.

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(50)
    SET @Test = 'A'

;WITH A AS (
  Select 'A is Selected' as SELECTED),
      B AS (
  Select 'B is Selected' as SELECTED)

IF(@Test = 'A')
  select * from A

IF(@Test <> 'A')
  select * from B
```

As of my Sample Test code above i got:

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>       Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>       Incorrect syntax near ','.

Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: CTE's are attached to a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement -- your example has none of those.  Conditional logic doesn't count...

Comment: To get the best answer possible you should post the code that generates the error you have. This will give you `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

> defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE,
>   or DELETE statement.

I guess you want something like this.

```
declare @Test varchar(50);
set @Test='A';

with A as
(
  select 'A is Selected' as SELECTED
),
B as
(
  select 'B is Selected' as SELECTED
)
select *
from A
where @Test = 'A'    
union all
select *
from B
where @Test = 'B';
```

Comment: So its not possible to use IF function if there is CTEs?

Comment: @BizApps you can not use iF in queries. You can use IF to control what queries should be executed but the CTE is a part of ONE query so you can not use IF to controle what CTE to use.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should simply put both queries inside an IF statement as follows:

```
IF (@Test = 'A')
  select * from A
ELSE
  select * from B
```

Comment: Actually, you **CAN** have multiple CTE definitions, separated by a comma - that's definitely **NOT** the problem!

Comment: I guess I just fail to see the need to join them like that.